# Print only one array list and average

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a list of array in java, which i may have to put a code for printing only the line with the name Artan, and the other is to print the average age. The code is this:

```
public class Student 
{
    public int nr;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String sex;
    public int tall;
    public int weight;
        Student(int nr, String name, int age, String sex, int tall, int weight) {

    this.nr = nr;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.tall = tall;
    this.weight = weight;
        }
    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
        Student[] arr;
        arr = new Student[10];
        arr[0] = new Student (1, "Artan", 19, "M", 175, 74);
        arr[1] = new Student (2, "Ertan", 30, "M", 179, 80);
        arr[2] = new Student (3, "Jin", 25, "M", 175, 75);
        arr[3] = new Student (4, "Isabella", 28, "F", 165, 54);
        arr[4] = new Student (5, "Anita", 21, "F", 164, 53);
        arr[5] = new Student (6, "Daniel", 32, "M", 180, 82);
        arr[6] = new Student (7, "Anton", 32, "M", 178, 75);
        arr[7] = new Student (8, "Miroslav", 40, "M", 186, 83);
        arr[8] = new Student (9, "Michael", 50, "M", 190, 95);
        arr[9] = new Student (10, "Katarina", 62, "F", 160, 74);

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println("Student List: "+ arr[i].nr+ " " + arr[i].name+" "+ arr[i].age +" "+ arr[i].sex+" "+ arr[i].tall+"cm  "+ arr[i].weight+"kg");
    }


    }
```

What should i do know, what code to write ?

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried?

Comment: Where is the list? To calculate average you should inside for loop define sum variabele and add the current student's age on each iteration and then divide this sum on number of students. To find student with name  - use if statement inside loop.

Comment: `i <= arr.length` this will cause `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` remove the equal sign !

Comment: The list is on the void. how do i write loop for and if for those 2?

Comment: First things first: you don't have a "list of array" here.  You have an **array of `Student` instances**.

Answer (score 0):

I would @Override `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" + "nr=" + nr + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", sex=" + sex + ", tall=" + tall + ", weight=" + weight + '}';
}
```

and use `Streams`:

```
Stream.of(arr)
        .filter(x -> x.name.equals("Artan"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

and to count average of age of all Students:

```
Double avg = Stream.of(arr)
        .mapToDouble(x -> x.age)
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
System.out.println(String.format("Average: %s", avg));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i].name.equals("Artan")){
    System.out.println("Student List: "+ arr[i].nr+ " " + arr[i].name+" "+ arr[i].age +" "+ arr[i].sex+" "+ arr[i].tall+"cm  "+ arr[i].weight+"kg");
  } 
}
```

You can also Override `toString` method and just print out student object:

```
System.out.println("Student : " + arr[i]);
```